# representation of symmetric group

Tags: group-theory

Please help me for the following statement. I do not understand what does it mean centralizer of a representation.

The imprimitive transitive representation of symmetric group $S_n$ of degree 2n has centralizer of order 2 in $S_{2n}$.

Comment: The representation is a homomorphism $\varphi : S_{n} \to S_{2 n}$. The centralizer in question is the centralizer in $S_{2 n}$ of the image of $\varphi$.

Comment: About $\phi$ in your answer is there any information?

Comment: @DerekHolt has given an answer to that below.

Answer (score 5):

For $n>2$, the symmetric group $S_n$ has a subgroup $A_{n-1}$ consisting of the even permutations that fix a point, and $|S_n:A_{n-1}| = 2n$. So the action of $S_n$ by multiplication on the left cosets of $A_{n-1}$ results in an embedding of $S_n$ into $S_{2n}$ with transitive image.

In general, by Lemma 4.2A of Dixon and Mortimer's book on permutation groups, if $H \le G$ with $|G:H|=k$, then the centralizer in $S_k$ of the image of the action of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$ has order $|N_G(H):H|$.

So applying that to the example, for $n>3$, $N_{S_n}(A_{n-1}) = S_{n-1}$, so the centralizer of the image of $S_n$ in $S_{2n}$ has order $2$.

Note that $n=3$ is an exception because $A_2$ is trivial and the centralizer has order $6$ (and is isomorphic to $S_3$) in this case.